# I want to merge two assoiciative arrays based on index

Tags: php

I have two arrays with indexes 1 to 10 and then I have to make it merge based on the index. So only some employee have to be added Salary.

I have tried using `array_merge()` but the output is not merging. I am not able to get proper output. Output coming is only the `employeeSalary`Array. 
 Why is it so?

```
$employee = array
(
0=>
    array("employee_id"=>1, "firstName"=>"Zahir", "lastName"=>"Alam", "Age"=>25, "Company"=>"Switchme", "Role"=>"Developer", "Department"=>"Tech"
        ,"Head"=>
            array("Id"=>3 , "Name"=>"Sourasis Roy")
    )
,
1=>
    array("employee_id"=>2, "firstName"=>"Amith", "lastName"=>"Manniken", "Age"=>25, "Company"=>"Switchme", "Role"=>"Developer", "Department"=>"Tech"
        ,"Head"=>
            array("Id"=>3 , "Name"=>"Sourasis Roy")
    )
,
2=>
    array("employee_id"=>3, "firstName"=>"Sourasis", "lastName"=>"Roy", "Age"=>28, "Company"=>"Switchme", "Role"=>"CTO")
,
3=>
    array("employee_id"=>4, "firstName"=>"Aditya", "lastName"=>"Mishra", "Age"=>29, "Company"=>"Switchme", "Department"=>"Tech", "Role"=>"CEO")
,
4=>
    array("employee_id"=>5, "firstName"=>"Priti", "lastName"=>"Lata", "Age"=>24, "Company"=>"Switchme", "Role"=>"HR")
,
5=>
    array("employee_id"=>6, "firstName"=>"Sumita", "lastName"=>"Nath", "Age"=>24, "Company"=>"Switchme", "Role"=>"HLA Head", "Department"=>"Crm")
,
6=>
    array("employee_id"=>7, "firstName"=>"Tarini", "lastName"=>"Khanna", "Age"=>22, "Company"=>"Switchme", "Role"=>"Content Writer")
,
7=>
    array("employee_id"=>8, "firstName"=>"Abhisek", "lastName"=>"Soni", "Age"=>23, "Company"=>"Switchme", "Role"=>"HLA", "Department"=>"Crm","Head"=>array("Id"=>5 , "Name"=>"Sumita Nath")
    )
,
8=>
    array("employee_id"=>9, "firstName"=>"Ankit", "lastName"=>"Pump", "Age"=>23, "Company"=>"Switchme", "Role"=>"HLA", "Department"=>"Crm"
        ,"Head"=>
            array("Id"=>5 , "Name"=>"Sumita Nath")
    )
,
9=>
    array("employee_id"=>10, "firstName"=>"Pogo", "lastName"=>"Laal", "Age"=>23, "Company"=>"Switchme", "Role"=>"Designer")
,
10=>
    array("employee_id"=>11, "firstName"=>"Sabina", "lastName"=>"Sekh", "Age"=>28, "Company"=>"Switchme", "Role"=>"HLA Head", "Department"=>"Crm")
,
11=>
    array("employee_id"=>12, "firstName"=>"Sanjay", "lastName"=>"Poudal", "Age"=>24, "Company"=>"Switchme", "Role"=>"HLA Head", "Department"=>"Crm"
        ,"Head"=>
            array("Id"=>10 , "Name"=>"Sabina Sekh")
    )
,
);

$employee_salary = array
(
7=>
    array("employee_id"=>7, "salary"=>"55,000"
    )
,
2=>
    array("employee_id"=>2, "salary"=>"60,000"
    )
,
9=>
    array("employee_id"=>9, "salary"=>"50,000"
    )
,
10=>
    array("employee_id"=>10, "salary"=>"30,000"
    )
,
);

$ar= array();
for($j=0;$j<count($employee);$j++)
{
    error_reporting(0);
    if($employee[$j]=$employee_salary[$j])
    {
        $ar=$employee[$j]+$employee_salary[$j];
        print_r($ar);
        echo "<br>";
    }
    error_reporting(0);
}
```

Comment: You're assigning here, not checking for equals: `if($employee[$j]=$employee_salary[$j])`

Comment: Then too there is no output it gives me error @ChrisWhite can you please help me out?

Answer (score 2):

AS said by chris white you forgot to add one more = for compare.and check array index is set or not in second array of employee_salary using **isset()**. like **if($employee[$j]==isset($employee_salary[$j]))**

```
$employee = array
(
0=>
    array("employee_id"=>1, "firstName"=>"Zahir", "lastName"=>"Alam", "Age"=>25, "Company"=>"Switchme", "Role"=>"Developer", "Department"=>"Tech"
        ,"Head"=>
            array("Id"=>3 , "Name"=>"Sourasis Roy")
    )
,
1=>
    array("employee_id"=>2, "firstName"=>"Amith", "lastName"=>"Manniken", "Age"=>25, "Company"=>"Switchme", "Role"=>"Developer", "Department"=>"Tech"
        ,"Head"=>
            array("Id"=>3 , "Name"=>"Sourasis Roy")
    )
,
2=>
    array("employee_id"=>3, "firstName"=>"Sourasis", "lastName"=>"Roy", "Age"=>28, "Company"=>"Switchme", "Role"=>"CTO")
,
3=>
    array("employee_id"=>4, "firstName"=>"Aditya", "lastName"=>"Mishra", "Age"=>29, "Company"=>"Switchme", "Department"=>"Tech", "Role"=>"CEO")
,
4=>
    array("employee_id"=>5, "firstName"=>"Priti", "lastName"=>"Lata", "Age"=>24, "Company"=>"Switchme", "Role"=>"HR")
,
5=>
    array("employee_id"=>6, "firstName"=>"Sumita", "lastName"=>"Nath", "Age"=>24, "Company"=>"Switchme", "Role"=>"HLA Head", "Department"=>"Crm")
,
6=>
    array("employee_id"=>7, "firstName"=>"Tarini", "lastName"=>"Khanna", "Age"=>22, "Company"=>"Switchme", "Role"=>"Content Writer")
,
7=>
    array("employee_id"=>8, "firstName"=>"Abhisek", "lastName"=>"Soni", "Age"=>23, "Company"=>"Switchme", "Role"=>"HLA", "Department"=>"Crm","Head"=>array("Id"=>5 , "Name"=>"Sumita Nath")
    )
,
8=>
    array("employee_id"=>9, "firstName"=>"Ankit", "lastName"=>"Pump", "Age"=>23, "Company"=>"Switchme", "Role"=>"HLA", "Department"=>"Crm"
        ,"Head"=>
            array("Id"=>5 , "Name"=>"Sumita Nath")
    )
,
9=>
    array("employee_id"=>10, "firstName"=>"Pogo", "lastName"=>"Laal", "Age"=>23, "Company"=>"Switchme", "Role"=>"Designer")
,
10=>
    array("employee_id"=>11, "firstName"=>"Sabina", "lastName"=>"Sekh", "Age"=>28, "Company"=>"Switchme", "Role"=>"HLA Head", "Department"=>"Crm")
,
11=>
    array("employee_id"=>12, "firstName"=>"Sanjay", "lastName"=>"Poudal", "Age"=>24, "Company"=>"Switchme", "Role"=>"HLA Head", "Department"=>"Crm"
        ,"Head"=>
            array("Id"=>10 , "Name"=>"Sabina Sekh")
    )
,
);

$employee_salary = array
(
7=>
    array("employee_id"=>7, "salary"=>"55,000"
    )
,
2=>
    array("employee_id"=>2, "salary"=>"60,000"
    )
,
9=>
    array("employee_id"=>9, "salary"=>"50,000"
    )
,
10=>
    array("employee_id"=>10, "salary"=>"30,000"
    )
,
);

$ar= array();
for($j=0;$j<count($employee);$j++)
{

    error_reporting(0);
    if($employee[$j]==isset($employee_salary[$j]))
    {
        $ar=$employee[$j]+$employee_salary[$j];

        print_r($ar);
        echo "<br>";
    }
    error_reporting(0);
}
```

Working Example : http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/dbi8-4krn

Comment: This solution would be correct according to one interpretation of 'to make it merge based on the index'. However it assigns salaries to employees with different employee_id, e.g. the last salary to Sabina with employee_id 11 instead of Pogo with employee_id 10. This is because the indices in the two arrays do not correspond to the employee_id in the same way.

Comment: @JohnB.Walugembe you are right but in question he want to join based on index

Answer (score 0):

Try out the following solution, with the values of arrays `$employee` and `$employee_salary` as given in the question.

```
$ar= array();

foreach($employee as $j => $v){
    $id = $v['employee_id'];
    foreach($employee_salary as $i => $u){
     $id_s = $u['employee_id'] ;

     if($id == $id_s){
       $ar = $employee[$j] + $employee_salary[$i];
       print_r($ar);
       echo "<br>";
     }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there will be an easy solution as well. Because you already made employee_salary array with the id key. So it will be like this .

```
Foreach($employee as $key=> $value)
{ 
     $employee[$key]['salary'] = $employee_salary[$value['employee_id']]['salary'];

 }
 Print_r($employee);die;
```

I think this will help you out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That should do

```
    $ar= array();
    for($j=0;$j<count($employee);$j++)
    {
        $ar[$j]=$employee[$j];
        if(isset($employee_salary[$employee[$j]["employee_id"]]) && $employee_salary[$employee[$j]["employee_id"]]['employee_id'] == $employee[$j]["employee_id"] ){
            $ar[$j]=array_merge($employee[$j],$employee_salary[$employee[$j]["employee_id"]]);
        }
    }
```

Pay attention to the array keys.